# how can i delete items from array in Matlab according to location without loop

Tags: matlab

- i have an array of numbers.
- i need to delete every 3th element without using for/while loop.

AB =

```
 1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: If starting from the 3rd element - `AB(3:3:end)=[];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make all 3rd elements in your array or vector an empty element like this:

```
ab =  [1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
ab(3:3:end)= []
```